# MS Access user defined function in select sql

Tags: ms-access

I am new to access
I would like to use a UDF in my SELECT sql statement like this:

```
select birthdate,GoMonth(birthdate,12) as yearold from data
```

The above statement will give a field name yearold 12 months after birthdate

---

```
function GoMonth(pDate,num) as datetime
    GoMonth=DateAdd("m",num,pdate)
end function
```

I don't know where to put or write the function
I am working with other databases and don't want to change my sql statements for each of them.

Comment: are you using Access as a frontend aswell or just as a database?

Comment: Why do you need a user-defined function? In your example, you can just use the DateAdd() function directly. Or have you just used a bad example that implies things that don't apply to your real situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Access as a frontend, put it in a module and make it a `public function()`. If you have another frontend, then you can't use user-defined functions with a MS Access database, as the functions are interpreted by Access and not the JET driver.